# Using an element of a constexpr array vs a const array to instantiate a template

Tags: c++, c++11

While answering [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520574/how-do-i-use-a-static-array-element-as-an-index-to-a-static-array-of-objects-tha), I ran into an issue that I couldn't explain.

It seems there is large enough difference between

```
constexpr size_t IntArray[2] = {1, 2};
```

and

```
const size_t IntArray[2] = {1, 2};
```

that the elements of the first can be used to instantiate a template but not the elements of the second.

Sample program that demonstrates the difference.

```
#include <cstddef>

template <size_t N> struct Foo {};

// Works fine
void test1()
{
   constexpr size_t IntArray[2] = {1, 2};
   const size_t i = IntArray[0];
   Foo<i> f;
   (void)f; // Remove unused f warning.
}

// Does not work
void test2()
{
   const size_t IntArray[2] = {1, 2};
   const size_t i = IntArray[0];
   Foo<i> f;
   (void)f; // Remove unused f warning.
}

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

I get the following compiler error using g++ 4.9.2.

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall    socc.cc   -o socc

socc.cc: In function ‘void test2()’:
socc.cc:17:8: error: the value of ‘i’ is not usable in a constant expression
    Foo<i> f;
        ^
socc.cc:16:17: note: ‘i’ was not initialized with a constant expression
    const size_t i = IntArray[0];
                 ^
socc.cc:17:9: error: the value of ‘i’ is not usable in a constant expression
    Foo<i> f;
         ^
socc.cc:16:17: note: ‘i’ was not initialized with a constant expression
    const size_t i = IntArray[0];
                 ^
socc.cc:17:9: note: in template argument for type ‘long unsigned int’
    Foo<i> f;
         ^
socc.cc:17:12: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
    Foo<i> f;
```

My question is why does the `constexpr` array work but not the `const` array?

Comment: Why do you think `constexpr` was introduced? I bet the `const` array would work if it had static storage duration, mind you. Can you present the standard wording that you think should make it valid as it is?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Use of `static` didn't make any difference. I have some understanding of why `constexpr` was introduced but there are gaps. This question illustrates some of that gap.

Comment: Then I refer you again to the standard; specifically, `[expr.const]` and friends. Happy reading!

Comment: What would you expect with `const size_t IntArray[2] = {1, bar()};` for `constexpr size_t a = intArray[0 /* or 1 */];`, it would be tricky and requires to remember for each index if it is a compile time value or not.

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks for that. I think that explains it. `const` does not guarantee the value can be determined at compile time while `constexpr` does.

Comment: @Jarod42, if you would like to post an answer, I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`constexpr` ensures that value is compile time value whereas `const` forbids only to modify the value.

Whereas it is easily to mark single const variable if it is a compile time value or not,
for C-array, it would require to remember that information for each index.

Even if we can do

```
const int two = 2;
constexpr int two_bis = two;
```

the following is not permit

```
const size_t IntArray[2] = {1, bar()}; // with non constexpr bar()

constexpr size_t a = intArray[0]; // we might know that is compile time value
constexpr size_t b = intArray[1]; // but this one is clearly not
```

Comment: precisely constexpr specifies that "it is possible to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time"